# How can I solve problem with Datatable at Laravel / Vue?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, datatable

I wanted to fetch data to datatable at Laravel. But I couldn' t manage to take any data and I' m taking error like "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" at page console. Is there any way to solve the problem?

index.blade.php

```html
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('header')
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
@endsection
@section('content')

<div class="container">
    @if(session("alert"))
        <div class="alert alert-{{ session(`alert-style`) }}">{{session("alert")}}</div>
    @endif
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
           
        <div class="mt-2 mb-2">
            <table id="productTable" class="table table-striped" style="width:100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            </table>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
@endsection

@section('footer')
       <component :is="'script'">
    
           $(function () {
    
            var table = $('#productTable').DataTable({
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                ajax: "{{ route('product.getData') }}",
                columns: [
                    {data: 'title', name: 'title'},
                    {data: 'description', name: 'description'},
                    {data: 'price', name: 'price'},
                    {
                        data: 'action', 
                        name: 'action', 
                        orderable: true, 
                        searchable: true
                    },
                ]
            });
            
        });
        
        </component>
@endsection
```

ProductController.php

```html
class ProductController extends Controller
{
    public function getData(Request $request)
    {
         $x = Product::select('id', 'title', 'description', 'price');
         return  Datatables($x)
               ->addColumn('edit', function($x){
                 return '<a href="'.route('product.edit', 
                 ['productId' => $x->id]).'">Edit</a>';})
               ->addColumn('delete', function($x){
                 return '<a href="'.route('product.delete', 
                 ['productId' => $x->id]).'">Delete</a>';})
               ->rawColumns(['edit','delete'])
               ->make(true);
    }
 }
```

web.php which specifies page routes is below.

```html
Route::get('/product', [App\Http\Controllers\ProductController::class, 'index'])->name('product.index');
Route::post('/getData', [App\Http\Controllers\ProductController::class, 'getData'])->name('product.getData');
```

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded js files locally and call them @vite expression. And the problem was solved.

```html
@vite(['resources/js/jquery.min.js', 'resources/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js'])
@section('footer')

       <component :is="'script'">
           $(function () {
    
            var table = $('#productTable').DataTable({
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                ajax: "{{ route('product.getData') }}",
                columns: [
                    {data: 'title', name: 'title'},
                    {data: 'description', name: 'description'},
                    {data: 'price', name: 'price'},
                    {data: 'edit', name: 'edit', orderable: false, searchable: false},
                    {data: 'delete', name: 'delete', orderable: false, searchable: false}
                ],
                columnDefs: [{
                    "defaultContent": "-",
                    "targets": "_all"
                }]
            });
            
        });
        
        </component>
@endsection
```